# How to check to which Bluetooth device my iPhone is connected

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, ios-bluetooth

I have two options to establish a Bluetooth connection with my iPhone.

1. Audio
2. Calls

(See image)
[image]

When I'm connected to the audio channel I can get the name of the device I'm connected to using AVAudioChannel as such:

```
let connectedAvSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
        let outputs = connectedAvSession.outputs
        print("OnBoardingCarSelectionViewController, createArray() =>\n currently connected devices via audio session = ", outputs)
        for output in outputs {
            let name = output.portName.description
            let uid = output.uid.description
            let port = output.portType.rawValue
            presentAlert("AV Channel", message: "name: \(name), uid: \(uid), port: \(port)")
        }
```

When I change the connection to calls, I can't get the name of the device anymore.
Is there a way I can know what I'm connected to when the connection is only set for phone calls?

Answer (score -1):

> An EAAccessoryManager object coordinates the attached accessories for
> an iOS-based device. Use the shared accessory manager to retrieve a
> list of connected accessories, and start and stop the delivery of
> connection and disconnection notifications.
>
> **Important** :-
> Blockquote
> Phone and iPad apps running on Macs with Apple silicon
> never receive connection notifications.

below will be used for getting the connected Device:-

```
var connectedAccessories: [EAAccessory]
The accessory objects correspond to the list of currently connected accessories.
```

link for your reference:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613821-connectedaccessories

Comment: updated sir....